# How to show that if average of squares equals square of average then all $X_i$ are equal?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Defining $A(X) = \sum_{i=1}^np_iX_i$, how would I show that given $A(X^2) = A(X)^2$, all $X_i$ must be equal?

I tried by contrapositive - assume they are not equal and show that $A(X^2) \ne A(X)^2$. I can show that

$$A(X)^2 = \sum_{i = j}^np_i^2X_i^2 + \sum_{i \ne j}^np_ip_jX_iX_j $$

But from here I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: Jensen's inequality.

Comment: I don't know how to make it strict

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Statements

Comment: Equality holds iff $X_1=X_2=...=X_n$, or if the considered convex function is linear. Since your function is not linear, that only leaves the first option.

Comment: Can we assume (since the title says "average") that $\sum p_i = 1$? Otherwise the statement isn't true. (Try $n=2,$ $p_1 = \frac 38,$ $p_2 = \frac 34,$ for example.)

Comment: Yes! Sum of $p_i$'s = 1.